# Determine the number of saddle points under specified conditions

Tags: calculus

Suppose a function with two variables $f(x, y)$ is smooth enough everywhere. If it has a local minimum and a local maximum, can we say that there are at least two saddle points as well? If so, how can we prove it? If not, then under what conditions shall $f(x,y)$ has extra saddle points.

Thanks for your answer! Any reference to other sources will be appreciated.

Comment: No, this is not true. There are functions with arbitrary number and types of critical points. This can be seen as follows - take a "generic" function $g(x,y)$ with discrete set of critical points of any types, then a topological disk $U$ containing only the desired critical points and we are done, since $U$ is diffeomorphic to the plane.

Comment: @sSs01 Can you proceed slightly further? What exactly is done? If we consider a gradient flow associated to $f(x, y)$ and find trapping region for it (or for its time-reversal) then the index along boundary is $1$ and trapping region can't contain **only** source and sink (local maximum and minimum respectively). But my assumption about trapping region might be quite restrictive.

Comment: But $U$ will not be a trapping region in general, the index along its boundary is not 1, it equals the sum of the number of local extrema minus the number of saddles inside $U$ (in case of a Morse function $f$).